# Android TextView autoSizeTextType not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to render the Text in single line using the autoSizeTextType.
But when i am executing the following code, it's not working properly.
e.x the number 1012 is rendered like-> first line: 101 , second line: 2

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"


        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/deepgreen"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="65dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"

        android:textColor="@color/white"


        app:circularflow_radiusInDP="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/zeroo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: Set `android:maxLines="1"`.

Comment: That's too not working :(

Comment: try giving height and width `wrap_content`

Comment: Sadly not working.

Comment: @RajdeepDas try `android:singleLine="true"` also

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your text has exactly one line,
`android:lines="1"`
should do it.

This will also work if you know that your text always has exactly some fixed number of lines: just set `android:lines` to that number. Unfortunately it doesn't work if the number of lines is variable.